# How to make button size equal to background image size in HTML?

Tags: html, button, background-image

I have the following code . The problem is that I am not succeeding in making the button size equal to the background image size. The size of the background image is 60x60 pixels. How should I code this?

```
  <tr>
                <td><button style="width: 60px; height: 60px;"><img src="darkSquare.jpg" /></button></td>
                <td><button style="width: 60px; height: 60px;"><img src="lightSquare.jpg" /></button></td>
                <td><button><img src="darkSquare.jpg" /></button></td>
                <td><button><img src="lightSquare.jpg" /></button></td>
                <td><button><img src="darkSquare.jpg" /></button></td>
                <td><button><img src="lightSquare.jpg" /></button></td>
                <td><button><img src="darkSquare.jpg" /></button></td>
                <td><button><img src="lightSquare.jpg" /></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button><img src="darkSquare.jpg" /></button></td>
                <td><button><img src="lightSquare.jpg" /></button></td>
                <td><button><img src="darkSquare.jpg" /></button></td>
                <td><button><img src="lightSquare.jpg" /></button></td>
                <td><button><img src="darkSquare.jpg" /></button></td>
                <td><button><img src="lightSquare.jpg" /></button></td>
                <td><button><img src="darkSquare.jpg" /></button></td>
                <td><button><img src="lightSquare.jpg" /></button></td>
            </tr>
```

I am getting the following output-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try, in CSS,

```
button {
  background-image:url('www.example.com/image.jpg');
  width:50px; /* or whatever */
  height:30px; /* or whatever */
}
```

That should do it, for all buttons.

Comment: Thanks for this. It worked! I have another question coming up soon.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be helpful to use this instead:

```
<input type='image' src='lightSquare.jpg'/>
```

Comment: Nice simple alternative to background image. Seems to allow setting width though CSS based on container and still having the height adjust automatically to remain square for square image.

Answer (score 1):

Use the image as background of the button. Make the with and height of the button same as the image size. IF the image size is 60X60 then the CSS will be

```
button {
display:block;
width:60px;
height:60px;
background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat top center;
}
```

this may help you...

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this problem recently, and all the answers asked to embed image into the button instead of the original html structure.

My solution to this is:

html:

```
<button style="width: 60px; height: 60px;">
  <img class="img-center" src="darkSquare.jpg" />
</button>
```

css:

```
.img-center {
  position: relative;  
  margin: auto;
}
```

As simple as that! This answer doesn't need you to change your html structure, especially for those who prefer this structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use the image as the CSS background of the button and size the button accordingly.

Even better: use an A-tag with display:block and use the CSS background there.

Comment: I tried this in CSS -

button
{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}


But it didn't work

Comment: You need to size the element in PIXELS to match the size of the image. Not percentages.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
Add a style tag:

```
<style>
.darkSquare{
    background: url('darkSquare.jpg') no-repeat;
}
.lightSquare{
    background: url('lightSquare.jpg') no-repeat;
}
.btn{
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    background:#FFF; 
    border:0;
}

</style>
```

Change your existing code to:

```
<tr>
    <td><button class="btn darkSquare"/></td>
    <td><button class="btn lightSquare"/></td>
</tr>
```